# JApplet not running properly in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, applet, japplet

I wrote a pretty basic applet program in eclipse:

```
public class SwingAppletDemo extends JApplet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1935096480915162747L;
    JLabel jl;

    public void init() {
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new SwingAppletDemo().makeGUI();
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void makeGUI() {

        jl = new JLabel("Press a button!");

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        add(jl);
    }   
}
```

It compiled fine and then I ran it as an applet by right-clicking on the `SwingAppletDemo.java` and then I selected `Run As > Java Applet`

The applet viewer opened but no label was displayed in it. Can anyone please tell me where did I went wrong, I referred to a few tutorials but couldn't find the necessary info.

I also tried running it in Google Chrome but there too only an empty applet was displayed.

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a new `SwingAppletDemo` in your `init` method which is never shown. You can simply replace:

```
new SwingAppletDemo().makeGUI();
```

with

```
makeGUI();
```

Comment: for that i would have to make `makeGUI()` `static` and my gui will not be created on EDT and also then i would not be able to call the `add()` and `setLayout()` method because an object would not even be created.

Comment: There's no need to make `makeGUI` static as you will be calling the method from the current instance of `SwingAppletDemo` in `init()`

Comment: yes, now it worked but how? why did it mattered which object reference i used?

Comment: You need to use the current instance/container which is already visible.

Comment: @SurenderThakran by the time init is called, the instance that init is being called on is the instance that is being displayed within the browser. If you create a new instance, then you are no longer dealing with the reference/instance that the user is seeing